# How to repair loose nails in a carpet threshold?

Tags: carpet, fastener, threshold

Apparently the carpet in my house has been replaced a few too many times. Most of the nails are loose so the threshold is basically being held in place by hopes and wishes.

I was hoping to improve the situation. Do any of the following ideas sound reasonable? If not, is there another suggestion?

- Could a longer nail be used? Do they make long nails for this application?
- Could a screw be used? Do they make screws for this application?
- Could I fill the hole with some sort of epoxy or filler and re-nail?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can just go buy a new strip. They're inexpensive and the holes will shift to new wood. You could also drill, countersink, and install additional nails.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest thing is likely to get a 1.5" long piece of tie wire.  Put the tie wire piece into the hole and then hammer the nail back into the hole.  The tie wire metal will allow the nail to get a secure hold in the stripped out hole.

Your threshold is fastened to the subfloor.  Really the only constraint here is the aesthetics of the fastener head in threshold.  If you are not picky about the color or appearance of the fastener head then you can use whatever will work.

Generally carpet will be 1/2" thick, your threshold is likely 1/4" higher and your subfloor is going to be ~3/4" so you want a 1.5" long fastener.

You can certainly make the hole in the metal larger to accept a larger diameter fastener and you can certainly use a screw.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how thick the wire should be? I just shoved several (8?) sections of roughly 0.5 mm wire (it’s what I had) into the hole and no luck. The nail is till very loose.

Comment: you put enough wire into the hole such that the hole is so full you'd need to hammer the nail for it to fit into the hole.  tie wire is fairly thick maybe a little thinner than the nail diameter itself.